# impossible to format a RAW usb flash drive

Tags: linux, windows, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I was trying to format my flash USB that is a RAW format.

- When I plug it windows asks me to format the USB I choose format I choose slow format but after 6 hours not even 1% done.
- I tried quick format and windows says couldn't format (something like
  that my Windows is French).
- I tried to format it from the command prompt `format e: /X /FS:FAT32` same thing after 6 hours not even 1% done.
- I tried quick format from the command prompt `format e: /Q /FS:FAT32` but windows couldn't format.
- I then ried with GParted; I tried to delete all the partitions and then format it. But I could not even delete partition. Trying to format without deleting partition but always same error and I tried to resize same error !

How do I fix this USB pen drive?

Will filling the disk with `0`s (from a Linux shell fix it) ?
I already know it will now work becuase I already tried the latter. It wrote 1.6Mb/4Gb 0s in around 1 hour when I used `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdf1`. I aborted it after that hour because my sister had to use the PC.

Any solution?

Comment: To get better performance from "dd"  try add this to the end bs=32768

Comment: What was the error message in `GParted`? Does this thumbdrive have a "physical" lock switch?

Comment: Well the erro was : LibParted Bug Found! Input/Output error during write on dev/sdf

Comment: The I/O error is a strong sign that the usb flash drive is failing/dying.

Comment: ok Thank you for your answer so you're telling me I can't fix the USB? no way to fix it? you mean throw it?? wrtiting in zeros won't fix it?